# Repeater in kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datarepeater

I used to work in Angular and now I'm beginning in kendo. I',m looking for something like ng-repeat(Angular) in Kendo. When I want to dynamicly repeat something from datasource (articles, buttons, pics etc.), I simulate repeater with unorderedList and listItem template.

There is radioButton repeater in code below:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: array" data-template="ul-template"></ul>
<script id="ul-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr:{name:name, id:id}, value:val, checked:selectedValue />
        <label data-bind="text:label, attr:{for:id}"></label>
    </li>
</script>
```

I think it's uncomfortable unlike ng-repeat.

Can anyone suggest correct approach for this issue?

Comment: ListView is the correct widget to use in this case.  What part exactly you find uncomfortable?